# Is the inline scaling of $\gtrsim$ or $\gtrapprox$ ok?

Tags: amsart, amssymb

I want to write the commands `\gtrsim` or `\gtrapprox`  from the `amsart` class  inline but the symbols look disproportionally big compared to x, y:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

 $x\gtrsim y$ or  $x\gtrapprox y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried `\scriptstyle` but it looks awful. Is the scaling correct and if no what to do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Selecting code and clicking the `{}` button above the text field will make the code highlighted as you see in my edit.

Comment: I see, I was struggling with it, thx!

Comment: The size of `>` and `~` is just the same as the independent symbols, which is how they are usually typeset.

Comment: But doesn't it look ugly is it just me?

Comment: (Unicode characters for copy-pasting convenience: \lessapprox: `⪅` \gtrapprox: `⪆`  \lesssim: `≲` \gtrsim: `≳` (*Negations:* \lnapprox: `⪉` \gnapprox: `⪊`\lnsim: `⋦` \gnsim: `⋧`))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The symbols of package `amssymb` for `\gtrsim` and `\gtrapprox` are a little larger than in other fonts (e.g., `MnSymbl`). The symbols can be shrunk via `\scalebox`. Small disadvantage: the shrinking also affects the line thickness.

The following example scales the symbols to 80% and respects the current math style. Furthermore, the symbol remains centered around the current math axis:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\GtrSim}{\smallrel\gtrsim}
\newcommand*{\GtrApprox}{\smallrel\gtrapprox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\smallrel}[2][.8]{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette{\smallrel@{#1}}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand*{\smallrel@}[3]{%
  % #1: scale factor
  % #2: math style
  % #3: symbol
  \sbox0{$#2\vcenter{}$}%
  \dimen@=\ht0 %
  \raise\dimen@\hbox{%
    \scalebox{#1}{%
      \raise-\dimen@\hbox{$#2#3\m@th$}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  $x\gtrsim y$ or $x\gtrapprox y$

  $x\GtrSim y$ or $x\GtrApprox y$

  $\scriptstyle x\GtrSim y$ or $\scriptstyle x\GtrApprox y$

  $\scriptscriptstyle x\GtrSim y$ or $\scriptscriptstyle x\GtrApprox y$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for!